# member returns undefined for no apparent reason

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

For some reason whenever I try to run this code it only responds with the else Block instead of the wanted if (member) result

(Before I get comments saying: "Well clearly the User is not in the Guild." that's the Case here)
[image: lol]

```js
let member = msg.mentions.members.first() || msg.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
console.log(member);
if (member) {
    try {
        const userInfo = new MessageEmbed()
            .setAuthor({ name: `${member.user.tag}`, iconURL: member.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }) })
            .setColor("BLUE")
            .setThumbnail(member.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
            .setTitle("User Info")
            .setDescription(
                `**Tag:** ${member.user.tag}\n**ID:** ${member.user.id}\n**Bot:** ${member.user.bot ? "✅" : "❌"}\n**Created At: <t:${Math.round(parseInt(member.user.createdTimestamp) / 1000)}:F>**\n**Joined At: <t:${Math.round(
                    parseInt(member.joinedTimestamp) / 1000
                )}:F>**`
            )
            .setTimestamp();
        return msg.channel.send({ embeds: [userInfo] });
    } catch (err) {
        log(err);
        return;
    }
} else {
    try {
        let fetching = await client.users.fetch(args[0]);
        const userInfo = new MessageEmbed()
            .setAuthor({ name: `${fetching.tag}`, iconURL: fetching.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }) })
            .setColor("BLUE")
            .setThumbnail(fetching.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
            .setTitle("User Info")
            .setDescription(`**Tag:** ${fetching.tag}\n**ID:** ${fetching.id}\n**Bot:** ${fetching.bot ? "✅" : "❌"}\n**Joined At: <t:${Math.round(parseInt(fetching.createdTimestamp) / 1000)}:F>**`)
            .setTimestamp();
        return msg.channel.send({ embeds: [userInfo] });
    } catch (err) {
        log(err);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried commenting out the else statement and removing the try, so you can actually see the error being printed out

Comment: Why do you expect the member to be cached? Why do you think it's a problem that you need to fetch them?

Comment: The sole purpose of fetch is for Users not being existent in the Server in the first place so it doesn't result in an User not found error

Comment: In addition, nothing is being printed out whilst trying the method Jason Martin suggested

Comment: What do you get from the `console.log(member)` line? Is it undefined?

Comment: Yes it returns undefined

Comment: Try console logging `args` before you get the member since it might be a problem with the ordering of the `args`

Comment: console.log(args) returns [ '739592876245385348' ]

Comment: Could it potentionally be caused by my messageCreate.js Event?
https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/uvurixocip.js